# Fan made story of the 70th Hunger Games

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, the-hunger-games

I read this story about 2 years ago. It was a fan-made and it told the story about Annie Cresta's victory in the 70th Hunger games.

I realize it's not a lot, but the things I remember from it are the things that are already mentioned in the books.

> Annie was allied with the boy from her district who got beheaded. She won because the arena was flooded, and being raised in district 4, she could swim better than the kids from other districts.

The writer created the story with the little information they got in the book in a very interesting way, telling the whole story before the game (reaping, being mentored by Finnick) and during the games.

Comment: These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (Fanfic) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question)

Comment: Do you remember any details? There are a number of fanfics on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you've given us enough information to identify this uniquely. I searched the internet for "fan fiction annie cresta", of which naturally there are many, but the best one I found to fit your description is:

1. [Annie's Story](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/8010442/1/Annie-s-Story) (2012). Annie's district partner is named Ethan. Story is 36 chapters, from Annie's reaping to her moving into the Victors' Village with Finnick and Mags.

Other stories which seem less likely to match:

2. [Annie Cresta, Genius](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/7848485/1/Annie-Cresta-Genius) (2014). Annie's district partner is named David. Story is 92 chapters, from before Annie's reaping to long after her Games (which finish in Chapter 37). Intercut with scenes from Finnick's point of view.
3. [*Undeniably Crazy*](https://www.wattpad.com/story/13440086-undeniably-crazy-annie-cresta-hunger-games-fan), which is unfinished and doesn't (yet? last update 2015) cover Annie's Games themselves. Unless you got hold of a complete version somewhere else.

Also a [couple](https://www.fanfiction.net/community/Annie-and-Finnick/100805/) of [lists](https://archiveofourown.org/tags/Annie%20Cresta*s*Finnick%20Odair/works), but I didn't see anything there which looks like a good fit.